# How to put a link into an h1 with haml in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, link-to

Hi :)
I'm new to haml and want something like this:

```
%h1
  =link_to "Home" :root
```

How could I realize this? Hope you can help me with this :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
%h1
  = link_to "Home", root_path
```

Comment: my pleasure, glad to be useful :-)